# Landlord charges (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, landlord, tenant, deposit

Our landlord entered our property illegally without permission to start repair work whilst we still had 2 weeks left on our tenancy agreement.

They want to charge us for this work even though they had entered without permission two weeks before our tenancy was due to end and didn't give us time to repair ourselves, which we had planned to do.

They also took our possessions from the apartment even though we were still in tenancy agreement. Two items were eventually returned after the landlord ignoring us for 24 hours, however one item was thrown away in a skip.

We were calm and polite in all our exchanges but now they're accusing us of numerous omissions and factual errors despite us having evidence to back up every claim.

What are our rights here? We will obviously dispute the deposit charges but we don't know what our rights are with entering illegally and removing our possessions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The nature of the repairs may be relevant to this question. If there was a (for example) a broken window the landlord probably had the right to make repairs (if only to prevent things getting worse). You say you were going to do the repairs yourself, so I guess this was damage you caused yourselves? - if so the landlord is entitled to have the work done by professionals (unless maybe you are qualified to make repairs yourself). Under normal circumstances your landlord should not be entering your home without your permission. Did you give him any reason to think you might have already left?